# Cannot Uninstall UserSolution: non-existent or broken web

Tags: powershell

I'm having some issues which I think are caused by some poor deployments.  I'm trying to remove them but I'm running into an error.

```
Uninstall-SPUserSolution -Identity WspImportProject1.wsp -Site http://test.foo.com

Uninstall-SPUserSolution : Unable to access web scoped feature (Id: c0cd4001-2a59-4c05-b243-81a701533601) because it references a non-existent or broken web (Id: f5bb9b29-344b-408b-8716-4a02c384f0c2) on site 'http://test.foo.com'.  Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.get_Item(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureEnumeratorBase.GetCachedWeb(SPSite site, Guid webId, Guid featureId)
At line:1 char:25
+ Uninstall-SPUserSolution <<<<  -Identity WspImportProject1.wsp -Site http://test.foo.com
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...allUserSolution:SPCmdletUninstallUserSolution) [Uninstall-SPUserSolution], SPFeatureIsOrphanedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUninstallUserSolution
```

When I've googled this problem, I've found a bunch of information saying that I need to restore the site first and then remove the solution, which is counter-intuitive.  I also see no way to restore the site.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  It is only growing worse as I try new solutions which also don't work, leaving my sharepoint installation cluttered with failed code.

**This is for my response to Meyer Denney**

Hey Meyer, Thank you for looking into my problem.  I tried the commands you gave but they did not find the solution, probably because these are UserSolutions instead of Solutions.

Compare:

These are the solutions that I cannot remove due to the above error:

```
PS C:\Users\Sam\Downloads> Get-SPUserSolution -site http://test.foo.com

Name                           SolutionId                           Status
----                           ----------                           ------
audit-demo-3.wsp               7b8a210d-058a-42be-8ad3-b5ccc2338f21 Activated
audit-demo-3-12c.wsp           2dc97848-10ac-47ea-a236-c876c18801a2 Deactivated
WspImportProject1.wsp          2dc97848-10ac-47ea-a236-c876c18801a2 Activated
```

These solutions are fine and I'm able to remove them through various methods:

```
PS C:\Users\Sam\Downloads> Get-SPSolution

Name                           SolutionId                           Deployed
----                           ----------                           --------
fooauditsystem.wsp             12ae832d-5a46-40a0-b6cc-1953d23efe50 True
auditbuttoncustomaction.wsp    7556915f-a042-4f02-903f-665594c8c5b9 True

PS C:\Users\Sam\Downloads> stsadm -o enumsolutions

<Solutions Count="2">
   <Solution Name="fooauditsystem.wsp">
      <Id>12ae832d-5a46-40a0-b6cc-1953d23efe50</Id>
      <File>fooauditsystem.wsp</File>
      <Deployed>TRUE</Deployed>
      <WebApplicationSpecific>FALSE</WebApplicationSpecific>
      <ContainsGlobalAssembly>TRUE</ContainsGlobalAssembly>
      <ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>FALSE</ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>
      <LastOperationResult>DeploymentSucceeded</LastOperationResult>
      <LastOperationTime>3/16/2012 12:28 PM</LastOperationTime>
   </Solution>
   <Solution Name="auditbuttoncustomaction.wsp">
      <Id>7556915f-a042-4f02-903f-665594c8c5b9</Id>
      <File>auditbuttoncustomaction.wsp</File>
      <Deployed>TRUE</Deployed>
      <WebApplicationSpecific>FALSE</WebApplicationSpecific>
      <ContainsGlobalAssembly>TRUE</ContainsGlobalAssembly>
      <ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>FALSE</ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>
      <LastOperationResult>DeploymentSucceeded</LastOperationResult>
      <LastOperationTime>3/16/2012 12:03 PM</LastOperationTime>
   </Solution>
</Solutions>
```

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Management Shell, try removing them with the following commands:

```
stsadm –o retractsolution –name MySharePointSolutionPackage.wsp –url http://webapplication –immediate

stsadm –o deletesolution –name MySharePointSolutionPackage.wsp
```

Comment: Hey Meyer thank you for your help.  Please see my edit to the original post.